# Crypto++ with Omnet++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, omnet++, crypto++

Does anyone use Crypto++ with Omnet++ in Windows. I need help with linking the library and using algorithms like AES in my .cc file in order to encrypt or decrypt exchanged messages.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: There were some questions about [Omnet++ on the user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/cryptopp-users/omnet$2B$2B%7Csort:relevance) a while ago. I think most Crypto++ users don't use it, so there are no replies. You should probably pursue your issues as a library linking problem with Omnet++. It could be any library, and not just Crypto++. Maybe something like [omnet++ add additional library](https://www.google.com/search?q=omnet%2B%2B+add+additional+library). The [OMNeT++ Users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/omnetpp) group may also be useful for you.

Comment: You do NOT need a crypto library inside a simulation. You are almost surely modeling your problem in a wrong way if you need to actually encrypt/decrypt something inside the simulation. This is not an answer to your question of course, but a good advice to re-evaluate your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add own libraries to an existing `OMNeT++` project go to `Project` | `Properties` | `OMNeT++` | `Makemeke` | select root or src directory | `Options`, then `Custom` | `Makefrag` and write the following lines:

```
EXTRA_OBJS += -LD:/foo/lib -lcryptopp
CFLAGS += -ID:/foo/include
```

where `D:/foo/lib` and `D:/foo/include` contain libraries (*.a or *.dll) and headers of `Crypto++`.

Comment: Thank you. Please Do you have an example of a simple project in omnet where the exchange of messages is crypted using cypto++. I don't know how to test whether the library is working with my project or not .

Comment: No, I don't have this kind of example.